# Using System C in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, systemc

I want to install system c library in Eclipse Luna in Mac OS.

I tried many solutions including: 
Project-> Properties->C++ General ->Paths and Symbols.

I still can't use the include systemc.h.

Please suggest another way of compiling system c code in Mac OS.

Comment: Do you have any code that you can include that shows what you have tried?

Comment: minor formatting changes, plus left comment for OP to improve question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use the `make`d systemc lib (assuming you followed the default INSTALL notes on version 2.3):

- open your systemc eclipse project
- open project properties
- c/c++ build tab tool settings set gcc c++ compiler includes the include path -l to your systemc include folder sitting in the downloaded folder
- go to gcc c++ linker and -l add `systemc` and -L add `/full/path/to_so_lib/`

if this is not enough aka `“error while loading shared libraries: libsystemc-2.3.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory”`

add to your `sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf` the -L linker path above. then `sudo ldconfig`